# Weird behavior of patch when filename is changed

Tags: diff, patch

Recently, I am learning `diff` and `patch`. I created two files, file `a` with content `abc` and file `b` with content `def`. Then I used `diff -u a b > p` and `patch < p`, it behaved correctly, as shown in the following:

```
[joe@joe-pc c]$ ls
a  b
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more a
abc
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more b
def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ diff -u a b > p
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more p
--- a   2018-12-20 22:56:33.865661540 +0800
+++ b   2018-12-20 22:54:15.241516269 +0800
@@ -1 +1 @@
-abc
+def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ patch < p
patching file a
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more a
def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more b
def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ ls
a  b  p
[joe@joe-pc c]$
```

But if I changed the filename from `a` to `ab`, something strange happened. The `patch < p` command told me that
`patching file b
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]`

```
[joe@joe-pc c]$ ls
ab  b
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more ab
abc
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more b
def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ diff -u ab b > p
[joe@joe-pc c]$ more p
--- ab  2018-12-20 22:57:29.767980973 +0800
+++ b   2018-12-20 22:54:15.241516269 +0800
@@ -1 +1 @@
-abc
+def
[joe@joe-pc c]$ patch < p
patching file b
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n] ^C
[joe@joe-pc c]$
```

The file contents are the same, but why in the second situation the `patch` cannot find the right file `ab` to be patched?

The above operations were performed in a Linux machine with `bash` shell.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I thought screenshots were more "authentic". Now I have pasted the terminal output into my question.

Comment: Awesome question. According to some random [https://www.opennet.ru/cgi-bin/opennet/man.cgi?topic=patch](man patch), it should automatically deduce file name to be `ab`, but in your case it uses `b` instead.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me: it does not work when I name files `ac`/`b` as well, but does work with `ac`/`bd`. It also starts working with any combination of names if I delete the second file altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's a feature of GNU patch**. As you haven't specific the file to patch, it has to be deduced from the input somehow. Basically, if you don't specify paths (only base names), it assumes that it has to patch the file with a shorter name, unless `--posix` command line argument is passed or `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set:

```
patch --posix <p
# or
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 patch <p
```

In your case, between `a` and `b` the first one is chosen correctly, but for `ab` and `b` the second one is chosen as patch target (as `patching file b` line suggests), but patching fails, hence the error.

You can also fix this behavior by either specifying patch target explicitly:

```
patch ab <p
```

### Digging into docs

GNU patch uses the following logic (see [patch's manual, "10.6 Multiple Patches in a File" section](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Multiple-Patches.html#Multiple-Patches)):

> First, patch takes an ordered list of candidate file names as follows:
>
> - If the header is that of a context diff, patch takes the old and new file names in the header. ...
>
> ...
>
> Then patch selects a file name from the candidate list as follows:
>
> - If some of the named files exist, patch selects the first name if conforming to POSIX, and the best name otherwise.

For "[uniform context format](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Example-Unified.html#Example-Unified)" the "old" file is mentioned after `---` (`a` or `ab` in your case), and the "new" file is mentioned after `+++` (`b` in your case).

If both files exist and `patch` is not configured to be "confirming to POSIX" (e.g. by setting `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable or `--posix` command line argument, see ["10.12 patch and the POSIX Standard" section of the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/patch-and-POSIX.html#patch-and-POSIX)), then `patch` will choose "the best" name out of two. "Name" here includes full path obtain from the patch file (doesn't matter in your case). Details are specific later:

> To determine the best of a nonempty list of file names, patch first takes all the names with the fewest path name components; of those, it then takes all the names with the shortest basename; of those, it then takes all the shortest names; finally, it takes the first remaining name.

"Name component" here is basically a folder/file name (e.g. `/foo/bar/baz` has three of them), "basename" is just the name of the file (`baz`).
So, if names are `a` (old) and `b` (new) and both files exist, there is no "best name", so the first one is patched.
But if names are `ab` (old) and `b` (new) and both files exist, then `b` is "better", so the tool tries to patch it and fails.

I have no idea why this behavior was made the default.

Comment: Wow, your answer is excellent! It feels non-intuitive that the information of old and new filenames are provided in the patch file but `patch` does not follow that rule... Thank you very much!